# Addition of NaBH4 and LiAlH4

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, phenols, organic-reduction, ethers

[image]

NaBH4 and LiAlH4 will be a source for the hydride ion and reaction will begin with addition of hydride by displacing the carbonyl group.

But I am not sure will it attack both the carbonyl or only one.
Moreover, Will it displace the chlorine at the bottom carbon?

Comment: There are three carbonyls here,  not two. Both of those reagents will actually react with all three of the carbonyls in this particular case.

Comment: In the book, when the compound reacted with NaBH4, it reduce only the first carbonyl and the bottom one to -OH. Whereas when it reacted with LiAlH4, it reduce all the carbonyls to -OH

Comment: This is a β-ketoester, though, and that changes things. I don't have time to draw out the reaction right now, but I wanted to make sure that if you get an answer, the person answering takes this into account.

Comment: What solvent is this in?

Comment: consider it as any acid.

Comment: LiAlH4/ether or THF will reduce the three functional groups forming a tetraol. NaBH4 in hydroxylic solvent will behave the same way. Normally, esters reduce slowly with sodium borohydride such that the acyl chloride and ketone can be reduced selectively. I have found beta-ketoesters to reduce not only the ketone rapidly, but also the ester group. Presumably, by initial reduction of the ketone and then the ester via a neighboring group participation.